# Room Sqlite Android Error. ColumnInfo does not define an element collate()

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-database

I'm using google **ROOM** lib to sqlite database in my android application.

I have created two database in my single app  with different Controller(user define).

here is code I have Implemented

**Database 1 :**

```
@Database(entities = {JobTable.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class JobRoomController extends RoomDatabase
{

public static JobRoomController controller;
public abstract JobTable jobTable();


    public static JobRoomController database(Context context)
    {
        if(controller == null)
        {
            controller =    Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    JobRoomController.class, "Job")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }

        return controller;

    }

    @Override
    protected SupportSQLiteOpenHelper createOpenHelper(DatabaseConfiguration config) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected InvalidationTracker createInvalidationTracker() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Database 2:**

```
@Database(entities = {DbTrackServer.class,DbGpsStatus.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class RoomControl extends RoomDatabase {




   public abstract IGpsStatus gpsStatus();
   public abstract ITrack track();
   private static RoomControl roomControl;
   public static RoomControl database(Context context)
   {
     if(roomControl == null)
       {
        roomControl =    Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            RoomControl.class, "mobileTracker")
                           .allowMainThreadQueries()
                           .build();
       }

       return roomControl;

   }
  @Override
    protected SupportSQLiteOpenHelper createOpenHelper(DatabaseConfiguration config) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected InvalidationTracker createInvalidationTracker() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But when I build my project it is showing gradle error.

**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @android.arch.persistence.room.ColumnInfo does not define an element collate()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have solved this problem by updating Room Lib from gradle file.**